# Como convertir el resultado de Eq( y , x), a una "Function(variable)" en Python sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Tengo entendido que los Gotchas no son funciones que se puedan llamar pero quisiera obtener algo igual a:

```
eq1 = Eq(y(x).diff(), y(x) + x)
eq2 = dsolve(eq1, y(x), ics = CI)
eq2(3)
```